# Is any test card number in stripe which has fixed balance limit?

Tags: testing, card

I need a test card number which has fixed balance limit to test payment for my project. For example: a card with $25.

I searched in stripe doc but didn't found. I also other sites but no where I found. Please help me to get a test card number with fixed balance limit.